# How do I create a generic repository with entity framework?

Tags: c#, git, entity-framework, generics

I have written 3 repositories with the same format. How do I create a generic repository?

```
public class MyRepository : MyDataRepositoryBase<ASD>
{
    protected override ASD AddEntity(MyDataContext entityContext, ASD entity)
    {
        return entityContext.ASDSet.Add(entity);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ASD> GetEntities(MyDataContext entityContext)
    {
        return from e in entityContext.ASDSet
               select e;
    }
}
```

This is where I am so far...

```
public class ComponentsRepository<T, U>:MyDataRepositoryBase<T>
    where T : class,new()
    where U : DbSet<U>, new()
{
    protected override T AddEntity(MyDataContext entityContext, T entity)
    {

        return entityContext.U.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

I am basically trying to find a way to call the DbSet "entityContext.ASDSet" without knowing what it is.

Any ideas or should I just let it go...

Comment: Just a link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: `DbSet` *is* a generic repository.

Comment: What I did was remove the DbSet entity and return using the recommended answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework has a Set Method so you could do this

```
return entityContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
```

But it won't check that you are passing in a class that isn't mapped.  So it's use at your own risk, will throw an exception if it's not mapped.  We have a base class that all our entity inherit from so we put a constraint on that, but even that there is no guarantee that a class is mapped in entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth the generic repository is considered an anti-pattern. This is the implementation I used to use:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IDbContext _context;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public Repository(IDbContext context) {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T entity) {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entity) {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    ...
}
```

My IDbContext:

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
    DbEntityEntry Entry<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    int SaveChanges();
    ...
}
```

I used this with a UnitOfWork that I did my saving through and repository retrieval. That said, I really do find creating repositories around my entities a lot cleaner.